# Как правильно сделать представление с динамическим содержимым (мультиязычность)?

Tags: php, yii2, mvc, views

Не могу осознать, как же правильно (+-) реализовать представление с динамическим содержимым?

На моём примере: мультиязычность. Необходимо вытягивать текста различных языков и подставлять во вьюху, т.е. вьюха одна и та же - только разный текст **внутри** неё.

Можно просто сделать обращение к БД прямо там, но тогда нет разделения логики.

Answer (score 1):

Во фреймворке есть функция `Yii::t('category', 'text')`, в зависимости от текущего языка она подставляет заданный перевод. Подробнее в [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html)

Answer (score 1):

В корне проекта (где папки config, models, controllers и т.д.) создается папка `messages`, в которой создаются еще одни подпапки для переводов, например `ru-RU` для русского, `en-US` для английского и т.д.

В каждой из этих папок хранятся файлы с переводом (как правило их много, например на каждую сущность свой, например `user.php`, `settings.php` и т.д.)

пример такого файла (например `general.php`):

```
<?php
return [
    'pgMyPage' => 'Моя страница',
    'pgProfile' => 'Профиль',
    'pgVideos' => 'Видеозаписи',
    'pgVideo' => 'Видеозапись',
    'pgSettings' => 'Настройки',
];
```

Далее в конфиге в компонентах подключаются переводы:

```
...

'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        '*' => ['basePath' => '@app/messages',  'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource'],
        'general', 'menu', 'profile', 'video', 'friends',
    ],
],

...
```

где `'general', 'menu'` и т.д. - это названия тех самых файлов с переводами.

А также желательно чтоб в настройках `'sourceLanguage'` был `'en-US',`

Во вьхах пишется просто:

```
<?= Yii::t('general', 'pgSettings'); ?>
```

где `general` - имя файла, где хранится перевод

`pgSettings` - ключ перевода.

В зависимости от того, какой в данный момент времени указан `language` - будет браться перевод из конкретной папки `messages`. Так, если `'language' => 'ru-RU'`, то за переводом фреймворк обратится в `messages/ru-RU/general.php`, если `'language' => 'en-US'` - обратится `messages/en-US/general.php` и т.д.

В какой момент переключать `language` - это уже вам решать.

Подробнее про интернационализацию можно почитать: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/tutorial-i18n.md

и

http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-tutorial-i18n.html