# Настройка i18n в Yii2

Tags: yii2, i18n

Доброго времени суток, помогите, пожалуйста с интернационализацией. Использую advanced шаблон.

**@common/config/main.php**

```
'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'frontend*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                    'fileMap'        => [
                        'main' => 'main.php',
                        'models' => 'models.php',
                    ],
                ],
                'backend*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                    'fileMap'        => [
                        'main' => 'main.php',
                        'models' => 'models.php',
                    ],
                ],
                'common*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                    'fileMap'        => [
                        'main' => 'main.php',
                        'models' => 'models.php',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

**@common/config/i18n.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'sourcePath' => __DIR__. '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    'languages' => ['uk-UA'], //Add languages to the array for the language files to be generated.
    'translator' => 'Yii::t',
    'sort' => false,
    'removeUnused' => false,
    'only' => ['*.php'],
    'except' => [
        '.svn',
        '.git',
        '.gitignore',
        '.gitkeep',
        '.hgignore',
        '.hgkeep',
        '/messages',
        '/vendor',
    ],
    'format' => 'php',
    'messagePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'messages',
    'overwrite' => true,
];
```

после выполнения yii message/extract @common/config/i18n.php создаются файлы:
@common\messages\uk-UA\common\models.php
**@common\messages\uk-UA\backendmain.php**
**@common\messages\uk-UA\frontendmain.php**

Что я делаю не так? =)

Comment: `Что я делаю не так?` - А в чем возникает проблема-то? Вы не ожидаете данных файлов в данных папках или прибегает белка и начинает взбивать подушку, а снусмумрик играет на волынке?......  может что-то **[отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520559/)**  поможет?

Comment: Обратите внимание на выделенный текст. Как формируются файлы: для common - правильно, для frontend и backend - не правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все оказалось просто.
не правильно проставлял слеши
к примеру категории common\main и common/main.
gii ошибки не выбрасывает.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых непонятна суть вопроса.

Если вы про папку "uk-UA"

То присмотритесь к:

```
 'languages' => ['uk-UA'], //Add languages to the array for the language files to be generated.
```

Если не в этом дело - то суть вопроса не ясна

Comment: нет, папки не правильно генерятся @common\messages\uk-UA\backendmain.php @common\messages\uk-UA\frontendmain.php

Comment: а должно быть backend\main.php, frontend\main.php. При этом common сгенерило норм.