# Перевести сайт на несколько языков

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Видел в просторах интернета несколько сайтов у которых есть несколько переводов сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка имеет формат, например https://site.com/ru/page,
где **page** - любая страница, например контакты.

А **/ru/** собственно ключ-значение перевода на нужный язык, логика думаю понятна, en, de, fr и т.д. и т.п..

Вопрос, как именно реализовать такой перевод на сайте, может это специальный движок типа Next.js или другое, чтобы было управлять страницами (пагинацией).

Google Translate API и тому подобное не предлагать! Спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522726/191482  как пример

Comment: Вообще часто в open-source проектах используется Transifex, туда записываются разные переводы строк, а потом уже эти строки переносятся в сам проект и используются там.

Comment: Зависит от того где вам нужно делать перевод - на фронте, или эе на бэке. С бэком @АлексейШиманский уже дал пример, на фронте вам нужно будет как-то обозначать элементы для перевода и использовать какой-то сервис, который будет делать его.